# Push ADODB.Recorset to Excel using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now i have classic ASP page having VB script that is pushing ADODB.Recordset to Excel. I have Excel macro that is calling this asp page to get data.

below is my classic ASP page with VB script that returns recordset.

```
dim rst
dim cntReportInstance
dim objBMISRpt
dim XDom

cntReportInstance = clng(Request.QueryString("cntReportInstance"))

set objBMISRpt = server.CreateObject("BMISRpt.clsBMISRpt")
set XDom =  server.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")

set rst = objBMISRpt.GetReportRecordset(clng(cntReportInstance)) // Method return recordset from COM component

rst.Save XDom,1

Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

Response.Write XDom.xml

Set xDom = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing

Response.End
```

Right now i am converting Classic ASP web application to ASP.NET MVC. so i wanted to change the above functionality.

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as below. so thought let me put the solution so it can help others too.

- I have added ADODB reference in my project.
- I got the Dataset and converted into ADODB Recordset with the help of below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13352/NET-DataSet-to-ADODB-Recordset-Conversion

- Finally returned the XML using the Response.Write()